# Creating a database of musicians for an app

Tags: android, database

What would be the best way to create a database of musicians, together with their songs and their music notes to be played on an instrument? Im trying to implement this into an app, in which the user would click on a musician and a list of their songs would appear then they could click on the song and the music note sheet would appear. What would be the best way to this?

Comment: android supports sqlite databases: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/data-storage/databases.html

Comment: How familiar are you relational databases?  If I was doing this, I would have a Musicians table that has a one to many relationship to the Songs table.  Then the Songs table would have a one to one relationship with the SheetMusic table that would probably have a reference to the sheet music image you want to display.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Whilst Android does support SQL lite there's a lot of boilerplate code and it's not particularly friendly to use (IMO). I suggest looking at Realm.

https://realm.io/docs/java/latest/